# Azure logic apps liquid transformation md5 support

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps

I am using logic apps with JSON_to_JSON transformation using a liquid template.
My liquid template looks as follows (it should produce a JSON independent of the input)

```
{% assign my_secret_string = "ShopifyIsAwesome!" | Md5  %}
{
    "test" : "{{my_secret_string}}"
}
```

The expected output would be a Md5 hash, but I keep getting

```
{
  "test": "ShopifyIsAwesome!"
}
```

Are Shopify filters supported in logic apps liquid transformation ?

Comment: @vijaya Many thanks for this suggestion. Tried it out, but unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> Are Shopify filters supported in logic apps liquid transformation ?

**Yes, Some of [Shopify filters](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters#md5) are supported in logic Apps.**

**For sample purpose i have taken one of Shopify filter Upcase and it works successfully.**

Here is the sample liquid template i have taken.

```
{
   "sample": "{{content.sample | Upcase}}"
   }
```

- As shown in below image created logic App.
  [image]
- The logic App ran successfully and got the expected output.
  [image]

So it supports Shopify filters. But when i tried MD5 as per your requirement getting the same output as you got.

[image]

Then i tried, below liquid template in Shopify and as shown in below image getting expected results.

```
{%- assign my_secret_string  = 'ShopifyIsAwesome!' | md5 -%}
{ "text" : {{  my_secret_string}}}
```

[image]
But when i ran the same template in logic Apps i am again getting same output as yours in logic Apps. Tried multiple ways with MD5 but still getting same output. So, AFAIK the issue with MD5 filter with logic Apps.
Refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform?tabs=consumption) it may helps.

Comment: seems we have the same conclusion. md5 filter does not work in Logic Apps liquid transformation. I have solved it now through a function app instead.

Comment: @Kermit754 yes Your right. Yeah, function app is other approach. Glad that works